# how to properly configure angular-meteor to have the content show up on the page

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

starting to build angular-meteor app
added urigo:angular-meteor
added urigo:angular-ui-router
created routes:

```
angular.module("app").config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'client/views/index.ng.html',
                controller: 'DropDownCtrl'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
    }]);
```

created index.ng.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>hello</title>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/ej.widgets.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/default-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/responsive-css/ej.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="../js/jsrender.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.globalize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jsondata.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/ej.web.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jsondata.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.syncfusion.com/12.2/js/ej.widget.angular.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="client/js//properties.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="DropDownCtrl">
      <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="cols-sample-area">
                <div class="frame" style="width: 50%; height: 27px">
                    <span>Select a section</span>
                    <div>
                        <div id="control" style="float: left; width: 45%">
                            <input id="bookSelect" ej-dropdownlist e-datasource="dataList" e-value="value" />
                            <h6><span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; position: absolute; margin-top: 4px;">Note:Two Way Angular Support</span></h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="binding" style="float: right; margin: auto; width: 45%">
                        <input type="text" id="dropValue" class="input ejinputtext" ng-model="value" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
}
</div>
<style type="text/css" class="cssStyles">
    .control {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .ctrllabel {
        padding-bottom: 3px;
    }

    #dropValue {
        text-indent: 10px;
    }

    #control #bookSelect_input_wrapper {
        width: 70%;
    }

    .input {
        height: 26px;
        text-indent: 10px;
        width: 67%;
    }

</style>

</body>

</html>
  <!--<div class="container">-->
      <!--<div class="row">-->
          <!--<div class="cols-sample-area">-->
              <!--<div id="Grid" ej-grid e-datasource="obj" e-selectedrowindex="selectedRow"-->
                   <!--e-allowgrouping="true" e-pagesettings-pagesize="4" e-pagesettings-currentpage="page"-->
                   <!--e-allowsorting="true" e-allowpaging="true" e-actionbegin="actionBegin">-->
                  <!--<div e-columns>-->
                      <!--<div e-column e-field="EmployeeID" e-headertext="Employee ID" e-textalign="right" e-width="90"></div>-->
                      <!--<div e-column e-field="LastName" e-headertext="Last Name" e-textalign="left" e-width="90"></div>-->
                      <!--<div e-column e-field="FirstName" e-headertext="FirstName" e-textalign="left" e-width="90"></div>-->
                      <!--<div e-column e-field="Title" e-headertext="Title" e-textalign="left" e-width="90"></div>-->
                      <!--<div e-column e-field="City" e-headertext="City" e-textalign="left" e-width="90"></div>-->
                      <!--<div e-column e-field="Country" e-headertext="Country" e-textalign="left" e-width="90"></div>-->

                  <!--</div>-->
              <!--</div>-->
          <!--</div>-->
          <!--<div id="sampleProperties">-->
              <!--<div class="prop-grid">-->
                  <!--<div class="row">-->
                      <!--<div class="col-md-3">-->
                          <!--Selected Row-->
                      <!--</div>-->
                      <!--<div class="col-md-3">-->
                          <!--<input type="text" id="selectedRow" name="name" class="e-ejinputtext" value="" ej-numerictextbox e-value="selectedRow"  e-maxvalue="3" e-minValue ="-1" e-width="100px" />-->
                      <!--</div>-->
                  <!--</div>-->
                  <!--<div class="row">-->
                      <!--<div class="col-md-3">-->
                          <!--Current Page-->
                      <!--</div>-->
                      <!--<div class="col-md-3">-->
                          <!--<input type="text" name="name" class="e-ejinputtext" value="" ej-numerictextbox e-value="page"  e-maxvalue="4" e-minValue ="1" e-width="100px" />-->
                      <!--</div>-->
                  <!--</div>-->
              <!--</div>-->
          <!--</div>-->
      <!--</div>-->
  <!--</div>-->
```

When loaded, browser console shows no errors, however, absolutely nothing shows up on the page.

When viewing the page source, I see all libraries being loaded, but the document body has nothing in it.

The main angular module - app.js is located under client/lib, and is being loaded properly.

Here is its content:

```
angular.module('app',['angular-meteor','ui.router',
    'ejangular']);
```

What can I ajust to have the contents of index.ng.html show up on the page?

Answer (score 1):

try to rename `index.ng.html` to `index.html`. I think I had the same problem and that was the solution.
Another option is to fork the tutorial project: https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular-socially , and use this as a skeleton for your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do angular-meteor is now to use the npm modules. It has the benefit of not needing to rely on Urigo for angular updates.

Remove the angular packages,

```
meteor npm install --save angular
meteor npm install --save angular-meteor
meteor npm install --save angular-ui-router
```

This is the code I use at the top of the controller:

```
'use strict';
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
```

As @oshai said, rename *.ng.html to be just *.html as well