# how to request angular version that is lower than default with angular-meteor

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to use a third party commercial JS library in my angular-meteor project
The vendor just informed me, that they only support angular version 1.3.11

Is there a way to install urigu:angular-meteor with this specific version of angular?

Comment: when I renamed the file to just plain index.html I started getting meteor errors: "bad formatting in html template", and meteor would not build the app

Comment: are you referring this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747253/how-to-properly-configure-angular-meteor-to-have-the-content-show-up-on-the-page/30753125#30753125 ? try to include .ng.html files from there (using ui router) and use angular and meteor directives over there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the meteor [documentation](https://atmospherejs.com/i/installing) you can set a version using `@=` so it should be like that:

```
meteor add angularjs:angular@=1.3.11
```

However, doing so you might have versions conflict like that:

```
>meteor add angularjs:angular@=1.3.11
 => Errors while adding packages:

While selecting package versions:
error: Potentially incompatible change required to top-level dependency: urigo:angular 0.6.8, was 0.8.4.
Constraints on package "urigo:angular":

To allow potentially incompatible changes to top-level dependencies, you must pass --allow-incompatible-update on the command line.
```

So you have here few alternatives:

- Downgrade urigo:angular: I think this is not a good option, there might be major changes since the package is pretty new.
- Convince the vendor to "take the risk"

Since `angular` is much more mature that `angular-meteor` and 1.3.11 to 1.3.15 should not have breaking changes, this option have a clear advantage.

If you do wish to use the first option, add `--allow-incompatible-update` to the command line.