# AngularJS Meteor $controller won't take binding argument -- angular version issue

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I am trying to write a test that has a before hook like so:

```
beforeEach(()=>{
  inject(function ($rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
    controller = $controller('userDetailsCtrl', {$scope: scope}, {locals: {userId: testUserId}});
});}
```

But I get a message that `compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled is not a function` I believe this is because angular-meteor is using AngularJS 1.5.3. Is there a work around for this or a way to force it to use a newer version of angular?

Comment: Did you try inject $controller ?

Comment: Yes sorry I left that out I have another before hook that does

      `beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$cookies_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $cookies = _$cookies_;
  }));`

Comment: But you still get same error message ?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: What version of angular and angular-mocks do you use ?

Comment: in my package.json I use 1.6.2 for both but I think angular meteor is overriding that somehow cause in my versions file it says `angular:angular@1.5.3_1`

Comment: I guess you need to find out how to set right version of angular. And some guys advise keep same version of angular and angular-mocks.

Comment: Yup thats basically what I'm asking. Is there a way to override the version of angular that angular-meteor seems to be using or if there is a work around for this specific issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that I can get it to work if I downgrade angular-mocks to 1.5.5 Does anyone know how to get it to work on later versions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757451/how-to-request-angular-version-that-is-lower-than-default-with-angular-meteor) you can get answer on your question "how to change version of angular in angular-meteor".

Comment: I played around with this a bit I think I might actually have the correct version of angular, maybe its the version of angular mocks but I don't know why that would be wrong